# How to detect the amount of force being placed on Sprite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I know if you use chipmunk you can use a function like this to determine how much energy is being exerted onto a sprite:

```
- (void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair seal:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB {
float energy = [pair totalKineticEnergy];

// if energy is large enough, remove the seal
if (energy > 5000.f) {
    [[_physicsNode space] addPostStepBlock:^{
        [self sealRemoved:nodeA];
    } key:nodeA];
}
```

}

I'd like to do the same thing, but **without** Chipmunk.  How can I determine how much force is being applied to my sprite at any given moment?

Comment: This question is a little obtuse--Chipmunk is the physics engine that handles everything physics, so without Chipmunk there is no force actually being applied because forces are something defined by Chipmunk. So your app doesn't actually know what forces are unless Chipmunk (or some other physics engine) is there to define them.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Yea, I'm still new to all of this.  I have gravity and a physicsWorld all set up.  And things are falling and moving correctly - but I haven't imported any sort of Chipmunk header.  Is Chipmunk what handles the physics in Xcode by default?

Comment: No, Chipmunk is a C-level physics engine that comes bundled with an Objective-C layer with Cocos2D. Try `import "CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h"`

Comment: I'm actually writing this in Swift.  Is it available for Swift?

Comment: You would have to implement the delegate protocol methods in swift, which I cannot help you with.